# Does vehicle damage hinder vehicle performance in Forza Horizon?

Tags: forza-horizon

When driving from event to event, occasionally my vehicle will take massive amounts of cosmetic damage.  I am curious is that damage shown on the vehicle is hindering that vehicle's performance.

I know I can instant repair by going to my body shop or going into an event menu & backing out, but I'm curious if I should do this before issuing a road challenge against a rival.

Is the damage just cosmetic or it is hindering performance ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All damage in the game is purely cosmetic. Looks like mechanical damage (from Forza 4) was removed to give the game an overall larger appeal to more casual racing gamers.

Comment: Can you provide a source to this answer?

Comment: The menu option I believe only says cosmetic damage.  Additionally, I've been watching a LP and he seems to think that it's only cosmetic.

Comment: @Zero Stack My playthrough of the game, and many different reviews of the game.